# OpenVPN very slow on dedicated server Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, vpn, openvpn, ubuntu-12.04

I installed an openVPN server on my dedicated server on ubuntu server 12.04.
Both my server and my current connection are on optic fiber.

I tested server bandwidth: upload 50mbit / download 88mbit

my home bandwith : upload 60mbit / download 96 mbit

But, when I connect to my vpn my average download speed on the same file is 8mbit

The server is brand new, it contains nothing except openvpn, fail2ban, and sometimes a minecraft server.
I obviously tested openVPN when disabling everything. When I download from my computer using VPN, the server CPU is only at 27% and memory is fine too so it's not a performance problem..

I followed this tutorial (which is in french but every methods are visible) : 
http://my1.fr/blog/creer-son-serveur-vpn-sous-debian/

Any idea ?

Comment: How are you testing your bandwidth?  Did you use something like iperf to test from yoour client to your VPN server?

Comment: I download with curl the same linux iso which is sent at least at 10Mb/s. For the upload I used SFTP.